# Type error does not allow me to run game sonar

Tags: python

I have some code, but I don't understand why it says type error. The code is:

```
    if sonarDevices > 1: extraSsonar = 's'
    else: extraSsonar = ' '
    if len(theChests) > 1: extraSchest = 's'
    else: extraSchest = 's'
    print('You have %s sonar devices left. %s treasure chest%s remaining' % (sonarDevices, extraSsonar, len(theChests), extraSchest))
```

The error is:
print('You have %s sonar devices left. %s treasure chest%s remaining' % (sonarDevices, extraSsonar, len(theChests), extraSchest))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What does "not all arguments converted during string formatting" mean?

Comment: 4 arguments and only 3 `%s`: that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have three placeholders in your string but four items in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Daniel said, you also are passing an integer to %s. Use %d as the placeholder for numbers.